# iOS not able to update the set text in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in `UITableViewCell` the text property is not updating.

My tableview delegate:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
KAPInputTableViewCell *cell = [self.registerTableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:KAPInputCellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[KAPInputTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier:KAPInputCellIdentifier];
}

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.inputTextField.placeholder = KAPLocalizedString(@"email", @"E-mail address");
        cell.inputTextField.text = @"Test";
        cell.tag = 0;
        cell.errorLabel.text = self.emailError;
        self.emailCell = cell;
        self.emailTextField = cell.inputTextField;
        break;
}
cell.inputTextField.delegate = self;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
}
```

Then when I call,

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.emailTextField.text);
```

Later in my ViewController on the press of a button the edited text still returns "Test" while I changed the input value.

Please help.

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly that what problem are you facing?

Comment: The problem I am facing is when I enter text in my UITextField in the simulator and afterwards I call self.emailField.text the text value is not updated as in the actual text field

Comment: You are setting text as @"Test" in `inputTextField` & after that you are passing the `inputTextField` text into `emailTextField`. Is it?

Comment: Have you created a property for `emailTextField`?

Comment: No I'm setting the text before I am editing the field

Comment: I have also got "@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *emailTextField;" in my .h file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80458/discussion-between-rajat-deep-singh-and-gigha).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80480/discussion-between-rajat-deep-singh-and-gigha).

Comment: Are you aware that you assigning the same text field object to the email text field and input text field? Why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just implement the UITextField delegate method:

```
   - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
   }
```

Here you will see your textField updated.